# Vbscript code wont execute properly in a subroutine within an HTA but does outside of subroutine

Tags: xml, vbscript, hta

Im having an issue i cant figure out. I have a simple hta that queries an xml and displays a message box containing a specific value. From what I can tell the code should work the same but its not.

The xml here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Food>
     <Fruit>
           <Name>Apple</Name>
     </Fruit>
</Food>
```

Here is the code that works:

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test</TITLE>
<hta:application
    applicationname="Test"
    scroll="no"
    singleinstance'"yes"
>
</HEAD>

<SCRIPT language="vbscript">

Dim xmlDoc, Target

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
            xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
            xmlDoc.Async = "False"
            xmlDoc.load("C:\Temp\example.xml")

            Set Target = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/Food/Fruit/Name")

msgbox Target.text

</SCRIPT>
```

When I try running from a subroutine, nothing happens. Do you know what I am missing?

Non-working code:

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test</TITLE>
<hta:application
    applicationname="Test"
    scroll="no"
    singleinstance'"yes"
>
</HEAD>

<SCRIPT language="vbscript">

Sub RunThisSubroutine

Dim xmlDoc, Target

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
            xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
            xmlDoc.Async = "False"
            xmlDoc.load("C:\Temp\example.xml")

            Set Target = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("/Food/Fruit/Name")

msgbox Target.text

End Sub
</SCRIPT>

<Body>
<input id=runbutton class= "button" type="button" value="Execute" name="button1" 
onClick="RunThisSubroutine">
</Body>
```

Comment: You’re missing the parentheses at the end of the `Sub` procedure definition, should be `Sub RunThisSubroutine()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sub function not working in HTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300218/sub-function-not-working-in-hta)

Comment: @user692942 The parenthesis are needed for the call with document (IE) mode 9 or higher. This HTA contains no DocType or X-UA-Compatible declaration, so it should be running in  IE 5 mode. It's possible the test machine has a FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry entry to set it to IE 9 mode, but then there  would be a `RunThisSubroutine is undefined` error instead of "nothing happens", as stated above. I tested the "Non-working code" and it ran without error and displayed "apple" when I clicked the button. Something else is going on.

Comment: @LesFerch Should have it regardless, it's poor programming not structuring code correctly imo.

Comment: @user692942 It's arguable because onClick is not a variable assignment and VBScript sub calls without an assignment or Call statement *require* no parentheses. Anyhow, that's all academic.  The question remains. What could be causing the "nothing happens" issue here? Maybe the OP will need to test under another account or on another machine.

Comment: @LesFerch I'm not talking about the call I'm referring to the procedure definition should end with parentheses.

Comment: @user692942 I see. I was looking at the suggested duplicate, which is not the issue here.

Comment: @LesFerch you obviously didn't read it very closely, because as far as I can see it's the same issue. Both have sub procedures that aren't executing from an event handler, how is that not considered the same issue?

Comment: @user692942 I read it very carefully. That HTA has a x-ua-compatible declaration setting ie=edge and the OP. said "causes an error claiming my function is undefined". There was a bunch of unnecessary guesses at would could be wrong, but it was simply the missing parentheses in the onClick call. That's not the issue here and the code tests fine for me.. Hopefully, the OP does more testing and posts back.

Comment: @LesFerch that isn't what the accepted answer states if you look there is still no parentheses in the `onclick` event handler, so not too careful. But regardless, it's clear now that the OP hasn't provided enough information either way and this continued argument is pointless.

Comment: @user692942 The first code attempt in that answer will still throw an error. The meta tag was removed from the updated code, leaving just the DocType declaration, so that script will run in IE 7 mode, where no parentheses are required in the call.

Comment: I added the () to the subroutine and the OnClick section, which allowed it to work. Thank you both for the insight and assistance.

Comment: Then either the code you posted here was not *exactly* the code that generated the error or your computer has a FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry setting that sets the document mode to IE 9 or higher. Be sure to add a DocType declaration and a X-UA-Compatible declaration to your HTA so that you control the document mode.See this [HTA Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69906838/15764378)

Comment: Correction: You didn't get an error. You got "nothing happens"  which suggests your code had an `on error resume next` but that's not in the posted code. Still a mystery here.

Comment: @LesFerch Thank you for the link. I've updated the code to include the doctype and declaration and will do that for future htas

Comment: @LesFerch So it was the parentheses after all that debating, good to know.

Comment: Yes, I've added my own answer to the duplicate and flagged this question.

Comment: The "nothing happens" was still not explained here. There are two scenarios that fit: 1) The script is running in document mode 5 and works fine, but was missing the "MsgBox" line when tested. Then both a MsgBox line and parentheses were added. The parentheses in that case would make no difference. 2) The script is running in document mode 11 via a FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry entry for mshta.exe and an error was generated, but was reported here as "nothing happens". In testing just now, I could find no way to suppress the error using On Error Resume Next.

Comment: @user692942 Oops, forgot the "mention" tags in the two previous comments.

Comment: @LesFerch agreed, the question doesn't have enough information either way.